# Hash iteration not returning subdirectory contents

Tags: ruby

I have a method that looks for subdirectories of a given parent directory. I store the parent directories in a hash and then pass the hash in as a parameter. I'm attempting to gather the contents of the subdirectories into an array that then gets output into a report.

I was having an issue where the contents of the array were only storing directory in the last value of the hash and i quickly realized that the contents were being overwritten through each iteration of the loop, so i created a new array to store the contents to after each iteration.

Before my changes, I was seeing the subdirectories being output as normal. Here's my code sample:

```
# stores subdirectory contents into an array
def store_directories(directories, folder_to_exclude)
  # changes working directory to the directory variable

  subdir_list = nil
  directories.each_value do |value|

    directory = "#{value}"

    puts Time.now.to_s + "  >  " +  "Updating search directory..."
    Dir.chdir(directory)

    # outputs only subdirectories with a creation date of older than 24 hours, except for folders names 'test'
    Dir.glob("*.*").map(&File.method(:realpath))
    puts Time.now.to_s + "  >  " +  "Gathering subdirectories..."

    subdir_list = Dir.glob("*").map(&File.method(:realpath)).reject{|files| (not File.directory?(files) && (File.mtime(files) < (Time.now - (60*1440))) && (not files == directory + folder_to_exclude)) }
    puts subdir_list

  end
 return subdir_list
end
```

The output would look something like this:

```
/path/to/parent/subdirectory1
/path/to/parent/subdirectory2
/path/to/parent/subdirectory3
/path/to/parent/subdirectory4 ...
```

This works pretty much the way that I want it to except that I'm only getting the contents of the last directory..

Here's my code sample after I made changes so that the contents of the array were not being overwritten:

```
# stores subdirectory contents into an array
def store_directories(directories, folder_to_exclude)
  # changes working directory to the directory variable

  subdir_list = directories.each_value do |value|

    directory = "#{value}"

    puts Time.now.to_s + "  >  " +  "Updating search directory..."
    Dir.chdir(directory)

    # outputs only subdirectories with a creation date of older than 24 hours, except for folders names 'test'
    Dir.glob("*.*").map(&File.method(:realpath))
    puts Time.now.to_s + "  >  " +  "Gathering subdirectories..."

    subdirectories = Dir.glob("*").map(&File.method(:realpath)).reject{|files| (not File.directory?(files) && (File.mtime(files) < (Time.now - (60*1440))) && (not files == directory + folder_to_exclude)) }
    puts subdirectories

  end
 return subdir_list
end
```

But here's the problem, now my output looks like this...

```
directory1
/path/to/parent1/
directory2
/path/to/parent2/
directory3
/path/to/parent3/
```

Suddenly my code is no longer looking for contents of the subdirectory but instead just returning the parent directories...

Comment: Be aware that `Dir.chdir(directory)` leaves the current directory changed. In your case it works because you give a full path, but if it is just a simple name, the next time you have a problem : look for _chdir has a side effect_ [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46955222/method-to-call-other-methods-multiple-times-using-hash-length-as-iterator/46968551#46968551).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
# stores subdirectory contents into an array
def store_directories(directories, folder_to_exclude)
  # changes working directory to the directory variable

  subdir_list = nil
  directories.each_value do |value|

    directory = "#{value}"

    puts Time.now.to_s + "  >  " +  "Updating search directory..."
    Dir.chdir(directory)

    # outputs only subdirectories with a creation date of older than 24 hours, except for folders names 'test'
    Dir.glob("*.*").map(&File.method(:realpath))
    puts Time.now.to_s + "  >  " +  "Gathering subdirectories..."

    subdir_list << Dir.glob("*").map(&File.method(:realpath)).reject{|files| (not File.directory?(files) && (File.mtime(files) < (Time.now - (60*1440))) && (not files == directory + folder_to_exclude)) }
    puts subdir_list

  end
 return subdir_list
end
```

This will essentially keep your old code, and append the new items to the subdir_list with every iteration, rather than overwriting. Note that the only real change here is the `subdir_list =` was changed to `subdir_list <<`

Comment: Thanks that did it!

Comment: Awesome! Would you mind marking this as the correct answer?